# Prove that $H \leq Z(G)$ if and only if $[H,G] = \{1\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For necessity, suppose $H \leq Z(G)$. Let $h^{-1}g^{-1}hg \in [H,G]$ be a generator, then $h^{-1}g^{-1}hg = 1$. Hence $[H,G]=\langle 1 \rangle = \{1\}$.

How can I prove the other direction?

Comment: The other direction is easy as well. Pick any $h \in H$and any $g \in G$. Then $[h,g]=1$, i.e. $h,g$ commute. By arbitrarity of $G$ you have that $h \in Z(G)$. By arbitrarity of $h$ you have $H \subset Z(G)$.

Comment: But we still haven't shown that $H$ is a subgroup?

Comment: Isn't this an hypothesis? I thought that "Let $H$ be a subgroup such that..." Please, write the details: what is $H$ supposed to be?

Comment: If $K \leq H \leq G$ then $K \leq G$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x\in G$ and $[x,G]=\{1\}$, in the sense that $[x,g]=1$ for every $g\in G$. Then $x\in Z(G)$, because $xgx^{-1}g^{-1}=1$ is equivalent to $xg=gx$.

Actually, this proves both directions at once:

> $H\subseteq Z(G)$ if and only if, for every $x\in H$, $[x,G]=\{1\}$

---

There is no need to assume $H$ is a subgroup, but usually the notation $H\le K$ for subsets of a group implicitly assumes $H$ and $K$ *are* subgroups, even if it is not specified at the outset.