# show that $[G_i, G] \leq G_{i-1}$ if and only if $G_i/G_{i-1} \leq Z(G/G_{i-1})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $1=G_1 \unlhd G_2 \unlhd ... \unlhd G_l = G$ be a central series with $[G_i,G] \leq G_{i-1}$.

It is east to see that $G_i \unlhd G$ for each $i$. But why is it the case that $G_i/G_{i-1} \leq Z(G/G_{i-1})$? I know that $G_i \leq Z(G)$ if and only if $[G_i,G]=1$, and if this holds then I've proved the statement. But I'm not sure why this is the case?

Comment: Use your other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307830/prove-that-h-leq-zg-if-and-only-if-h-g-1. This is equivalent to the above one modding out by $G_{i-1}$ and putting $H=G_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $p:G\rightarrow G/G_{i-1}$ the quotient map. Let $g\in G_i$, for every $x\in G$, $[x,g]\in G_{i-1}$ implies that $p([x,g])=[p(x),p(g)]=1$, we deduce that $p(g)\in Z(G/G_{i-1})$ since $p$ is surjective.

Comment: How do you deduce that $p(g) \in Z(G/G_{i-1})$?

Comment: this is equivalent to saying that for every $y\in G/G_{i-1}$, $[p(g),y]=1$, you can write $y=p(x), [p(g),y]=[p(g),p(x)]=p([g,x])=1$ since $[x,g]\in G_{i-1}$.